# CSVHelper - CSV Parsing error with double quotes in header

Tags: c#, .net, csv, .net-framework-version, csvhelper

I am having a parsing error when i am trying to read a CSV file using CSVHelper.
In the header i have Quotes, so i don't know how i can handle the CSVHelper to set to read quotes in the header reader.

csv:

```
"Index","Header"
1,name
2,surname
```

c#

```
public class Object
{
    public int Index {get; set;}
    public string Header {get; set;}
}

using (var reader = new StreamReader("path\\to\\file.csv"))
using (var csv = new CsvReader(reader, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture))
{
    var records = csv.GetRecords<Object>();
}
```

Then i have a parse error because it have the quote character at the start and in the end of every word of header, how i can fix it?

Comment: *"I have an error"* - would be better to say "I get a CsvParseException 'Error on line 1; unexpected character "' or whatever the error actually is. Please always avoid saying "I got an error" and not saying exactly what it was

Comment: Is https://github.com/JoshClose/CsvHelper/issues/1209 applicable?

Comment: i was not having a clear error in my try catch it was telling that the reader cannot parse int32, apart from that i will try the comments on this issue later. Thanks for all the help

Comment: Sounds pretty clear to me. Full type name and exact message text of any exceptions you get, please

Comment: Fixed with IgnoreQuotes

Comment: Post it as an answer

Comment: And how now with CsvHelper 20.0.0? IgnoreQuotes has been removed.

Answer (score 0):

The final answer was to use IgnoreQuotes.

```
using (var reader = new StreamReader("path\\to\\file.csv"))
using (var csv = new CsvReader(reader, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture))
{
    csv.Configuration.IgnoreQuotes = true
    var records = csv.GetRecords<Object>();
}
```

Comment: Can you please add the `nuget` you are using.

Comment: @JackFrost Its CSVHelper.